# VBA UDF function causes excel to "not respond"

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I have some very simple code that is causing Excel to crash.

I have debugged the variables as can be seen in the code and they look fine except that after only a few seconds Now() does not change and waitTime does not change - although the times are different from each other i.e. the time has not moved forward (for example, Now might be stuck at 3:00:05 and waitTime is stuck at 3:00:09).

And application.wait does not wait the 5 seconds I've asked for.

And the cell font color does not change either.

I do not know how to debug any further than this.

In the worksheet "sheet1" I have the following cell entries -
    in C8 I have a number that I change manually. In D8 I have

```
=if(C8>25,"yup",startFlash(C8))
```

And this works fine. It calls the function with no problem.  Here is the macro code:

```
Dim waitTime As Date, stopTime As Date


Function startFlash(x As String)
    Beep
    stopTime = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()) + 2, Second(Now()))
    Call sflash
    MsgBox "done"  
End Function

Sub sflash()

    Do While waitTime <= stopTime

        With Sheet1.Range("c8").Font
            If .ColorIndex = 3 Then
              .ColorIndex = 5
             Else
             .ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End With

        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

        Debug.Print Now(); waitTime; stopTime

        Application.Wait waitTime
    Loop

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on what code to change to stop Excel from crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on time alone if there is any chance of 'walking over' midnight; include the date in your start and stop datetimes.

```
Option Explicit

Dim waitTime As Date, stopTime As Date

Function startFlash(x As String)
    Beep
    stopTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 2, 0)
    'Debug.Print stopTime
    Call sflash
    MsgBox "done"
End Function

Sub sflash()

    Do While waitTime <= stopTime

        With Sheet1.Range("c8").Font
            If .ColorIndex = 3 Then
              .ColorIndex = 5
             Else
             .ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End With

        waitTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        'Debug.Print Now; waitTime; stopTime

        Do While Now < waitTime: DoEvents: Loop
    Loop

End Sub
```

Looping through the [DoEvents Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728.aspx) until your times meet is a better method.

Comment: Thank you.  I've run it 2 times and it hasn't crashed.  However, the cell color does not change until I hit 'ok' after the msgbox i.e. the colors do not flash/blink which is the other thing I need to happen.

Comment: This might have to do with the video load on your computer. I had to zoom in to notice the difference (old eyes) but C8 was alternating font color between red and blue.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll have to check the video issue.  I debugged the colorIndex and it does change i.e. the if statement works.  Something else to play with and learn about.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've just tried the code on another computer with the same result of cell C8 not changing color until I hit ok at the msgbox "done".  I realize this is another question, but can you offer any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps it's a version thing; I was using xl2010 originally but my xl2013 and xl2016 are sporadic. Putting `Application.Screenupdating = False` Before the `With...` and `Application.Screenupdating = True` after the `End With` seems to help.

Comment: ok, this is really weird - with screen updating added as you've suggested, there is no change.  However, if I ctrl-break, debug and then F5, the blinking works fine from that point on.

Comment: I'll try to look closer at this tomorrow but I have to admit that I am clueless at the moment.

Comment: I've been scouring the internet for the past few hours.  Seems to be a problem for others with no clear cut solution.  I've tried a myriad of expressions based on others' suggestions but no luck.  Could there be an application or workbook or sheet or cell setting that I may be missing?

Comment: Jeeped - would you mind if I posed the last part of my problem as a new stackoverflow question?

Comment: Please do. I am at a loss for a solution so far.

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry for bothering you again, but I've tried to ping you in our chatroom to draw your attention but you seem to be busy. I need your help if your time permits.